# How can I launch the Lightning-"create Event"-Dialog with given Date and Time

Tags: xul, thunderbird-addon, thunderbird-lightning

I would like to open the thunderbrid-lightning-create event dialog with a given date and time.
Currently I have:

```
window.open("chrome://calendar/content/calendar-event-dialog.xul",
                      "xulschoolhello-some-window",
                      "chrome,centerscreen")
```

Which opens the Dialog as expected. How can I set now the Date and Time?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [openEventDialog](https://dxr.mozilla.org/comm-central/rev/4f8486123b817d6b18bf2684a0f7e5facf725ce6/calendar/base/content/calendar-item-editing.js#365) function, which also defines some window arguments down in line 434 if you want to do it manually.

```js
/**
 * Opens the event dialog with the given item (task OR event)
 *
 * @param calendarItem      The item to open the dialog with
 * @param calendar          The calendar to open the dialog with.
 * @param mode              The operation the dialog should do ("new", "modify")
 * @param callback          The callback to call when the dialog has completed.
 * @param job               (optional) The job object for the modification.
 * @param initialDate       (optional) The initial date for new task datepickers
 */
function openEventDialog(calendarItem, calendar, mode, callback, job, initialDate)
```

You can call this function directly on the window object of the main Thunderbird window. This could for example be done by adding a XUL overlay to the window that has a script block that eventually calls this function.

Comment: How can I call this function from an other addon?

Comment: I've added the information, let me know if this is clearer.